# How to sort by date but based on day (floored day) in mongoose (node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongoose

The goal is to sort by date but floored to nearest day as I'm also sorting by user votes. Basically, to sort by day and highest votes so the most votes for the day come up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you need to store both the precise date and a pre-floored date in your mongodb data and then sort by the pre-floored one. You will see this pattern a lot for doing case-insensitive search on string fields as well. With mongoose, you can use a pre-save hook to automatically set the pre-floored date based on the precise date. Once the data is there, the sorting part just works normally.